# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click' - Follow Button Instagram Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to create a bot to hit a button in the browser, in another window hit the follow button Instagram and go back to the first window. And It's OK to switch windows,

but I can't did the bot press the follow button in Instagram (I created a bot independent only for hit the follow button and OK but don't work in the new script).

Where am I wrong? The code:

```
window_after = browser.window_handles[2]

time.sleep(10)

seguir = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/div[1]/div[1]/span/span[1]/button').click()

browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1])
```

The error:

```
seguir = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/div[1]/div[1]/span/span[1]/button').click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

When I put "Element" the error is this:

```
Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/div[1]/div[1]/span/span[1]/button
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not `find_element_by_xpath` (no plural on elements)?

Comment: `find_elements_by_xpath` finds all elements match the pattern and return them as a list. Try `find_element_by_xpath`

Comment: When I put without s, the error is: Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/div[1]/div[1]/span/span[1]/button

Comment: That means it can't find element by the given path. Check your path see if it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

*Try doing like the following Example*

```
seguir = firefox_browser.find_element(By.XPATH("//button[contains('Follow')]"))
seguir.click()
```